Use prompt tokens instead of prompt for sdxl? for the purpose of interpolation
Working from the following code, but would like to use the tokenized prompt so that I can interpolate between 2 prompts and produce a video output. The creation of the video from frames is easy enough, but I’m stuck here at the beginning. Any advice is appreciated.
from diffusers import AutoPipelineForText2Image
import torch


torch.cuda.empty_cache()


pipe = AutoPipelineForText2Image.from_pretrained(
    "stabilityai/sdxl-turbo", torch_dtype=torch.float16, variant="fp16"
)
pipe.to("cuda")

for item in pipe.components:
    print(item)

prompt = "A cinematic shot of a baby racoon wearing an intricate italian priest robe."

# tokenizing and encoding the prompt into embeddings.
prompt_tokens = pipe.tokenizer(
    prompt,
    padding="max_length",
    max_length=pipe.tokenizer.model_max_length,
    truncation=True,
    return_tensors="pt",
)

image = pipe(prompt=prompt, num_inference_steps=1, guidance_scale=0.0).images[0]

# save image
image.save("output.png")

